# What is Stack overflow and Heap overflow and how to mitigate them in C language?

Tags: c

So i was trying to learn what does stack overflow and heap overflow means and how its being exploited in C language? Is there any mitigation strategy we can apply to counter these exploitations? How the overflow occurs? If you can explain with an example it will be helpful to me as a starter.
TIA..

Comment: In order to realy get into the depth of these issues you need some basic knowledge in OS (for example Linux), Process, process structure and more. see my answer below.

Comment: check this very detailed explanation - https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/process-stack

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

- a stackoverflow occurs when you call a recursive function and the recursion depth becomes too deep, or if you have very large local arrays in a function.
- a heap overflow (or rather memory exhaustion) occurs when you use dynamic memory allocation with `malloc` and related functions and there is simply no more memory available.

Examples that will (most likely) cause a stack overflow:

```
void foo(int x)
{
   foo(x+1);   // never ending recursive call
}

void bar(int x)
{
  int largelocal[10000000];   // very large local array
  printf("Hello\n");
}
```

Example that will (most likely) cause memory exhaustion:

```
for(;;)
{
  malloc(10000);   // allocating memory over and over
}
```